# JQuery function with media width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a JQuery script, which fade in a sidebar, when scrolling down for 500px. This is working without any errors. However, I tried to wrap it in another function, which checks the media size. The fade in should only work, if the media size is greater than 1024. It does not work and I don't get any error in the console. Can you pls help me?

```
jQuery(function($) { 

  function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {

$(window).scroll(function() {    

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("body").addClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").addClass("nav-fade");
    }
    else {
        $("body").removeClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").removeClass("nav-fade");
    }
});
    } else {

    }
  }

});
```

Comment: You are declaring function checkPosition() but you are not calling it right? Put all this function outside jQuery(function($) { and call it inside. jQuery(function($) { checkPosition() });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrapped the whole JS inside a function which never gets called.

You should

- remove the function declaration (`function checkPosition()`)
- or call the function (`checkPosition()`)

Removing the declaration:

```
jQuery(function($) { 

    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {

$(window).scroll(function() {    

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("body").addClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").addClass("nav-fade");
    }
    else {
        $("body").removeClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").removeClass("nav-fade");
    }
});
    } else {

    }

});
```

Calling the function:

```
jQuery(function($) { 

  function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {

$(window).scroll(function() {    

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("body").addClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").addClass("nav-fade");
    }
    else {
        $("body").removeClass("right_side_menu_opened");
$(".side_menu").removeClass("nav-fade");
    }
});
    } else {

    }
  }

  checkPosition();

});
```

*Note:* if you want to check viewport size, you could use `$(window).width();` to get the width of viewport.